# Can't import * from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

If I try to execute `from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import *` it fails. I've tried do uninstall package with `pip uninstall sqlalchemy`  and reinstall it again. I've tried removed the version from the Ubuntu repositary (the `python-sqlalchemy`-package) but it wasn't installed. I've got to a clean directory and tried the same command. Still don't work. This is both with sqlalchemy 0.7.8 and 0.7.9.

This is the traceback:

```
In [1]: from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import *
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/nine/slask/<ipython-input-1-7f210e4ec48b> in <module>()
----> 1 from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import *

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/__init__.py in <module>()
   1252 """
   1253
-> 1254 from .api import declarative_base, synonym_for, comparable_using, \
   1255     instrument_declarative, ConcreteBase, AbstractConcreteBase, \
   1256     DeclarativeMeta, DeferredReflection, has_inherited_table,\

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/api.py in <module>()
    101
    102
--> 103 class declared_attr(interfaces._MappedAttribute, property):
    104     """Mark a class-level method as representing the definition of
    105     a mapped property or special declarative member name.

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_MappedAttribute'
```

For the record, I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it works. This is what i did:

- I uninstalled sqla with pip
- Deleted the remaining files manually (`rm -fr /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy`)
- Reinstalled sqla with pip and now it works.